# vb.net How to reference a local variable

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have the below code:

```
Dim ColMap As Integer = Val(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(dr("MappedTo").ToString(), 3))  
Dim ValorLeido As String  

ValorLeido = temp(dr("NoColumn").ToString())  

Select Case ColMap  
      Case 101  
         _101 = ValorLeido  
      Case 102  
         _102 = ValorLeido  
      Case 103  
         _103 = ValorLeido  
End Select
```

Is there a way that I can use something like me("_" & ColMap) = ValorLeido ??

Comment: You need to include more of your code, there is allot going on in that block that is ambigeous to the passer-by. Or add a little more specifics to your question. It's hard to tell what your objective is.

Comment: It is technically possible using Reflection.  If the target variables are Public you can use the legacy CallByName() function making the syntax slightly easier.  It would only work if the variables are in a Class, though, as CallByName() won't work with Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example showing **CallByName()**.  Note the the target variables are **Public**:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public _101 As String
    Public _102 As String = "{Default Value}"
    Public _103 As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Debug.Print("Before: _102 = " & _102)

        Dim ColMap As Integer = 102
        Dim ValorLeido As String = "Hello World!"

        Dim varName As String = "_" & ColMap
        CallByName(Me, varName, CallType.Let, ValorLeido)

        Debug.Print("After: _102 = " & _102)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And here's the same thing via **Reflection**, which allows the target variables to be **Private**:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form1

    Private _101 As String
    Private _102 As String = "{Default Value}"
    Private _103 As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Debug.Print("Before: _102 = " & _102)

        Dim ColMap As Integer = 102
        Dim ValorLeido As String = "Hello World!"

        Dim varName As String = "_" & ColMap
        Dim fi As FieldInfo = Me.GetType.GetField(varName, Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        fi.SetValue(Me, ValorLeido)

        Debug.Print("After: _102 = " & _102)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: A different application design could have you use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to associate the two values together.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a storage medium meant to hold a series of ID's to a series of values such as a Dictionary

```
Dim ColMap As Integer = Val(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(dr("MappedTo").ToString(), 3))  
Dim ValorLeido As String = temp(dr("NoColumn").ToString())  
Dim Lookup as New Generic.Dictionary(of Integer,String)
Lookup(ColMap) = ValorLeido

' 1 way of Reading values out of a dictionary safely
Dim Value as string
Value=""

if lookup.trygetvalue("101",value) then
    msgbox("Value for 101 is """ & value & """")
else
    msgbox("Value for 101 is not found)
end if
```

You could also access via a single indexed property if this structure already exists

```
public property Value(Index as integer) as string
    get
         select case index
             case 101
                  return _101
             case 102
                  return _102
             case 103
                  return _103
             case else
                  Throw new exception("Index not present " & index)
    end get
    set (value as string)
        ' populate with reverse process ...
    end set
end property
```